# Integrate Metamask to a Wix website

Tags: metamask

me and my team are benn working on a new crypto project. We did a Wix website and we want to integrate Metamask to this website to do presales of our token. The problem is that we really Don't know how to do it. We just know that we need to host metamask to an other domain but that's it. If someone can help us or do it for us, it will be great and we can p a y you :)
tm : @Nayliiss